# C++ const_cast over a dynamic_cast and vice versa

Tags: c++, c++11, dynamic-cast, const-cast

I have a doubt about a line of the code written by my professor.

[This is the full code](https://pastebin.com/KnnjLuaD).

The relevant function is:

```
std::vector<AbstractButton*> removeUnchecked() {
    std::vector<AbstractButton*> v;
    CheckBox* p;
    for(auto it = Buttons.begin(); it != Buttons.end(); ++it) {
      p = const_cast<CheckBox*>(dynamic_cast<const CheckBox*>(*it));
      if(p && !(p->isChecked())) {
    v.push_back(p);
    it = Buttons.erase(it); --it;
      }
    }
    return v;
  }
```

The class `Gui` has a `std::list<const AbstractButton*> Buttons` and the function `std::vector<AbstractButton*> removeUnchecked(){}` wants a `vector` as its return type. We had to remove from the `Gui` every checkable buttons with the attribute `checked == false` and put it into the returned vector.

The professor wrote:

```
CheckBox* p = const_cast<CheckBox*>(dynamic_cast<const CheckBox*>(*it));
```

performing a `dynamic_cast` first, and then a `const_cast`.

If I had written:

```
CheckBox* p  = dynamic_cast<CheckBox*>(const_cast<AbstractButton*>(*it))
```

`const_cast` first, and then `dynamic_cast`, would it be the same thing?

Comment: Yeah, they are the same. Why?

Comment: I'd argue the net effect is the same (although language lawyers might be able to pick some nuance that I am not).   `const_cast`, given a null pointer, will produce a null pointer.   `dynamic_cast` will produce a null pointer if the supplied pointer is either null or does not point at an instance of the class being converted to.  `dynamic_cast` can be used to add/maintain `const`ness, but not remove it.   So the first produces a pointer (potentially null) which is `const` qualified, then removes removes that `const`ness.   The second removes any `const`ness first, then `dynamic_cast`s it.

Comment: `const_cast` is a code smell regardless of where it's used. Storing pointers to const in **private** variables when you're storing non-const widgets seems unnecessary. If your class was really big and you wanted the user to explicitly having to express the intent of accessing the non-const version, you'd simply store a wrapper type implementing a conversion operator to `AbstractButton const*` (`operator AbstractButton const*() const`) and `AbstractButton const* operator->() const` in addition to adding a function like `GetAsNonConst`...

Comment: Almost forgot: the wrapper type should of course also implement `AbstractButton const& operator*() const` and perhaps `operator bool() const` and comparison operators to `AbstractButton const*`; this adding all these operators make the objects usable as if they were pointers and also allow you do use `wrapperObject.GetAsNonConst()->...` to access the wrapped pointer to non-const...

Comment: @fabian -  The `operator *()` or `operator bool()` are not needed in this case.   The code is working with standard containers of raw pointers (one `const` qualified, and one not).  So `*it` will be a pointer, either way, and the casts (in both options shown) are converting raw pointers - there is no wrapper type in play.   (I do agree that the `const_cast` is a code smell, but that's not what the question was about).

Answer (score 1):

Both orders of the cast should be fine and do the same thing.

`const_cast` will return a pointer pointing to the same object as before or a null pointer value if the argument is a null pointer value.

`dynamic_cast` either returns a pointer pointing to a `CheckBox` object or a null pointer value, without depending on the `const`, except that it refuses to cast away a `const`.

---

From looking at just the code you linked, it isn't clear to me though why the objects are stored as `const` pointers in the first place.

`const_cast` is one of the more dangerous casts. You must guarantee that the pointer which you `const_cast` doesn't actually point to an object with `const` type. If it does, then trying to modify the object through the new non-`const` pointer will cause undefined behavior.

---

However in the code in your link there is an unrelated bug in the function. It uses `std::list::erase` to remove the elements while iterating over the list. It correctly uses the return value of `std::list::erase` as a new iterator to the next element.

But then, because the `for` loop always executes `it++`, in the loop body you `it--` the return value from `std::list::erase` to compensate.

However, if you just removed the first element of the list, then `std::list::erase` will return a pointer to the new first element of the list, i.e. the new `.begin()` iterator. Decrementing this pointer is not allowed and causes undefined behavior.

Comment: The `const_cast` is used to remove the constness from the item pointed by the iterator because we have to return a `std::vector<AbstractButton*>`. Are you saying that we could have used the const_cast inside the push_back(here) right?

But I've prefered to do everything in a single line.

Comment: @darkgumma No, I am saying that I don't know why the vector and list private members store `const` pointers.

Comment: I think because the professor wants to be sure if a person knows when to perform a `const_cast `( for example we had a list with `const` pointers and we had to return a vector without the `const`. @user17732522

Comment: @darkgumma OK, but you would normally try to avoid doing such things. They might have chosen it because it is difficult to come up with good examples to use `const_cast`. But still, the important point is that you are not allowed to simply `const_cast` any pointer you want to, You need to make sure that it isn't possible that the pointer refers to an object that is declared `const`. In your example code this seems to be guaranteed in the sense that `insert` takes only non-`const` pointers, so if the class is used correctly it should never be given a pointer to a const object.